# What is the pattern for this time format?

Tags: java, android

I have an API which gives me the date string on the following format, I want the pattern for this time format, and would like to convert this back to an instance of `Date` class. `Date.parse(String s)` in `java.util` is deprecated in android. so what is the method for do so?

Tnx.

```
Mon, 14 May 2018 11:47:11 GMT
```

Comment: What attempts have you made to solve your issue? It is expected from Askers to show research effort.

Comment: You can read this [Date and Time Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to know more about date time format

Comment: @TrongHoang oracle is not accessible where I live.Tnx

Comment: Search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's like 2018.  People really should be making use of the Date/Time API introduced in Java 8 or the [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("Mon, 14 May 2018 11:47:11 GMT", formatter);
System.out.println(ldt);
ZoneId zoneID = ZoneId.of("GMT");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(zoneID);
System.out.println(zdt.format(formatter));
```

Which outputs...

```
2018-05-14T11:47:11
Mon, 14 May 2018 11:47:11 GMT
```

You should also be making better use of the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) which provide examples of the available formatter properties

> But DateTimeFormatter is only available in android 26+, my app runs on 16+

and

> but it prints it : GMT+00:00

The following...

```
String format = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z";
String input = "Mon, 14 May 2018 11:47:11 GMT";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.UK);
Date date = parser.parse(input);
parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(parser.format(date));
```

prints...

```
Mon, 14 May 2018 11:47:11 GMT
```

But I'm using Java 8 on the desktop, so there might be a difference for Android

Comment: Tnx, But DateTimeFormatter is only available in android 26+, my app runs on 16+

Comment: Then you need to mark you question as such, otherwise we're just assuming you're running on a desktop - but there seems to be some [backports available for Android](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=threeten+backport+antroid&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: Sorry about that, I did it, but some guy came in and edit it,and deleted the android tag!

Comment: @RezaHamzehie  It's okay, I put it back

Answer (score 2):

```
String format = EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z
String input = "Mon, 14 May 2018 11:47:11 GMT";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
Date date = parser.parse(input);
```

MMM returns short month name (JAN), if required full use MMMM.
H returns hour in 24 hour format, use K for 12 hour format.

Comment: it's good, but there is +00:00 attached to end of it. 
and Tnx.

Comment: @RezaHamzehie GMT is +00:00

Comment: @MadProgrammer , yeah but I want to settle down with just " GMT", but it prints it : GMT+00:00.

Comment: @RezaHamzehie With a little wrangling to get into `GMT` time zone, it prints `Mon, 14 May 2018 11:47:11 GMT` for me

Comment: @MadProgrammer, mybe it's my timezone then

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
                                                          //Mon,  14 May  2018 11:47:11 GMT
SimpleDateFormat mySimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT");
```

Comment: I think `'T'` will just deliver the letter T.

Comment: it says the 'T' is illegal

Comment: @JoopEggen yes by mistake i forgot update answer please check updated answer